# How do I get the Uri of a file that I just downloaded using the DownloadManager class?

Tags: java, android

I need content uri of the downloaded image. I got the id of the download but I am not able to get any type of uri using getUriForDownloadedFile() function.

```
String imgName = "WallPics" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                DownloadManager.Request download = downloadImage(imgName);
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                long downloadId = manager.enqueue(download);
                Uri cUri=manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadId);
                Log.e(TAG, "onClick: "+downloadId );
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick: "+cUri);
```

The downloadImage function is defined as:

```
private DownloadManager.Request downloadImage(String imgName)
{
    DownloadManager.Request download=new DownloadManager.Request(imageUri);
    download.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE| 
DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
    download.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
    download.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("",imgName);
    return download;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need content uri of the downloaded image

Since you are using `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("",imgName);`, I would expect your code to crash, as `""` is not a valid value for `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()`.

So, let's instead pretend that you are using:

```
setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,imgName);
```

In that case, your file is in:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), imgName);
```

If you truly need a `content` `Uri` for that, use `FileProvider` to serve that file yourself.

Comment: Thanks for answering but my uri is still null. Do i need a broadcast reciever to first fetch if the download is successful or not?

Comment: @RachitBhutani: "Thanks for answering but my uri is still null" -- the `new File(...)` code snippet from my answer will not return `null`. A `Uri` created from that `File` via `fromFile()` will not be `null`. "Do i need a broadcast reciever to first fetch if the download is successful or not?" -- well, yes, insofar as you do not know if the file is ready for use otherwise.